# e.preventDefault() cannot stop enter on claude.ai

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, dom-events, tampermonkey

I'm working on a TamperMonkey script and I want to modify the default behavior of the Enter key in a text box. Currently, pressing Enter submits the text, but I want it to insert a new line instead. Specifically, I want Enter to act as if Shift+Enter was pressed, which inserts a line break (br tag) in the text box.

Here are the requirements I'm trying to achieve:

Pressing Enter should insert a new line in the text box.
Pressing Shift+Enter should maintain its original behavior of inserting a line break.
Pressing Ctrl+Enter should perform the default action of submitting the text box.
However, my current TamperMonkey script is not working as expected. Shift+Enter and Ctrl+Enter work fine, but pressing Enter still submits the text box instead of inserting a new line. Additionally, for debugging purposes, I would also like to insert the text "ABCDE" when Enter is pressed, but nothing happens.

I suspect that there might be an event or a front-end framework with a higher priority that is preventing the default Enter key behavior from being modified.

Can anyone suggest a solution or provide insights into how I can overcome this issue? Is there a specific event or front-end framework that I should be aware of that has a higher priority in preventing default events?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Claude.ai Swap Enter and Ctrl+Enter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Swap enter and ctrl+enter on claude.ai
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.claude.ai/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=claude.ai
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
  const target = document.querySelector('body');
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      if (mutation.type === "childList") {
        const editor = document.querySelector('.ProseMirror');
        if (editor) {
          editor.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            if (e.key === 'Enter' && !e.ctrlKey) {
              e.preventDefault();
              const sel = window.getSelection();
              const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

              const br = document.createElement('br');
              const textNode = document.createTextNode('abcde'); // The text to insert
              range.deleteContents();
              range.insertNode(br);
              range.insertNode(textNode);

              // Move the caret to after the break line and text
              range.setStartAfter(textNode);
              range.setEndAfter(textNode);
              sel.removeAllRanges();
              sel.addRange(range);

              return false;
            }
            if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.ctrlKey) {
              e.preventDefault();
              const form = document.querySelector('form');
              const submitButton = form.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
              const event = new Event('submit');
              form.dispatchEvent(event);

              if (event.defaultPrevented) {
                submitButton.click();
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });

  const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true,
  };

  observer.observe(target, config);
})();
```